# Call stored procedure from inside Java class and write to console?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I want to be able to call a stored procedure from a Microsoft SQL Server database and list the results to the console (that is to start with). At someone I want to put all that data either to a JTable or to the web but first I will be happy if I can display it to the Console.

I think that the problem is that I cannot (or probably do not know how) to establish a connection to the database.

How can I connect to my Microsoft SQL Server database? (I have seen it done before and I think that it was 4 lines of code. I want this to work on my machine so I can start testing out some of the stored procedure.

Java Code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class SQLServerTest {
    private ResultSet[] yourResult;

    private void showSuppliers(ResultSet[] rs) throws SQLException {
            Connection con =
                                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection");
            Statement stmt = null;

            String query = "select * from PeopleOne";

            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs[0] = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        }

     private void ShowResultsToConsole(ResultSet[] rs) throws SQLException {
      for (ResultSet r : rs) {
        int c = 0; 
        r.getString(c);
      }
    }

    public static void main(String[] p) throws SQLException {
         SQLServerTest temp = new  SQLServerTest();
         temp.showSuppliers(temp.yourResult);
             temp.ShowResultsToConsole(temp.yourResult);
    }

}
```

Comment: whats stopping you from calling a stored procedure if the procedure contains select statement it can be called using execute query and for the part of connecting to sql server from database i say what is stopping from using google for and i'll suggest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047414/java-program-to-connect-to-sql-server-and-running-the-sample-query-from-eclipse

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.

```
public class DbTest {

static final String DRIVER_CLASS = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/mydb";
static final String DB_USER = "username";
static final String DB_PASS = "password";

public static void testQuery() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Class.forName(DRIVER_CLASS);
    Connection jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,
            DB_USER, DB_PASS);

    ResultSet rs = jdbcConnection.createStatement().executeQuery(
            "SELECT TOP 10 field_name FROM table_name");

    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("field_name"));
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    testQuery();
}
```

This assumes you have [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) JDBC Driver in your classpath.

If you need to use [Microsoft JDBC Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx) instead you should have it in your classpath and change the following in the code.

```
static final String DRIVER_CLASS = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=mydb";
```

You should always close your resources properly as described in [Java / JDBC: Best design pattern to close database connection when exception occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160557/java-jdbc-best-design-pattern-to-close-database-connection-when-exception-occ)

Comment: I think that it is in the class path but how do I make certain that it is? This is something in Java that I don't have to do to often.

Comment: on the password part all I see is the login which would look something like this. WY/abcd12345   and no password. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Are you getting a particular error or stack trace when you run the code? If so, can you post it? To set the classpath see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434213/adding-jdbc-driver-to-classpath. Can you connect to your database using an external database client like http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/ for instance?